# Use of the clause: "in the status quo"

Tags: word-usage

What does everyone think about opening a sentence with the clause: "In the status quo...." For example: "In the status quo, all statues are grey." I don't like it, and I can't find examples of this usage in larger publications with large archives, but I am failing to convince my interlocutor. Thoughts?

Comment: What is your question exactly? You should formulate your question in a way that it's not to broad and doesn't just ask for an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would think that it would be better to say "The *status quo* is that all statues are gray".

My Latin is horrible, but wouldn't it be "*In statu quo*..." not "In the *status quo*..."?

Also, many of the statues around here have a nice greenish patina.

Answer (score -1):

I hardly ever hear the phrase “status quo”, and never read it. I think it is a colloquial phrase. When I have heard it, it is in the form “Keep the status quo”. The only other place that I have read/heard it is in the name of a band.

A phrase with what is probably similar meaning that I have heard more often, including by academics, is “All other things being equal, …”

Comment: It is not a colloquial phrase, and it is quite common. Please limit your responses on this site to things you know about or can research.